# I'm with you only when there is happiness And I leave you when you are all in sadness

Tags: riddle

> I am your best friend
>
> But I'm not the same like the others
>
> I'm with you only when there is happiness
>
> And I leave you when you are all in sadness

*Hint:*

> if you run he also run

Comment: Is it laughter? But hard to imagine it being your "best friend".

Comment: not the right answer. . best friend is part of the clue :)

Comment: Is it health ? Not sure it fits entirely the two first statements though.

Comment: i edited my riddle.. 'coz it's kinda vague before..

Comment: hint:  you can see it :)

Comment: it's not literally happy and sad..

Comment: `you are all in sadness`; do you literally refer to a group here or just a single entity?

Comment: just a single entity :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are:

> a person's shadow

I am your best friend

> A shadow is frequently around a person

But I'm not the same like the others

> A shadow isn't the same as a human friend

I'm with you only when there is happiness

> Since you added the hint "it's not literally happy and sad", I take it to mean that a shadow is only around when it's sunny. (sunshine=happiness)

And I leave you when you are all in sadness

> I take it to mean that the shadow disappears when it's cloudy. (cloudy=gloomy/sad)

I'll give hint 'coz i made a mistake: if you run he also run

> A shadow does what a person does.

Comment: you got it :D  i'm not sure if my riddle was composed correctly..

Comment: I think it would have been much better if you provided more clues at the beginning, especially since you tried to use happiness and sadness in a figurative sense.

Answer (score 2):

Is it:

> A smile

I am your best friend

> It's mine at least :)

But i'm not the same like the others

> Each smile has it's own characteristics

I'm with you only if you are happy

> Obviously :)

And leaves you when you are sad

> Yes, sadly :(

Comment: not the right answer.. :)

Comment: I'm very curious what it would be :)

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> luck

?

best friend, because

> with luck you can get far

not same like the others

> here I'm not sure, because actually there is no reference for the others

with you when you are happy

> because the happy people have luck

leaves you when you are sad

> because when you are sad, it seems like the luck is running from you

Comment: Good thinking :)

Comment: not the right answer :) I edited my riddle.. the last two lines has deep meaning. it's not literally happy and sad :)

Comment: i made a mistake for the last two lines :( but i fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

I have this feeling that it's waaay more simple that what I have.

> Either contentment, or understanding.

*I am your best friend, but I'm not the same like the others*

> Both things are good things to have as "companions", but they're not exactly your typical best friends.

*I'm only with you when you're happy, And I leave you when you're sad*

> Contentment is basically happiness, so I think that answer is pretty explanatory, and I think that if you understand why something works, you'd be happy, and when you don't you'd be confused and upset.